# Can we use CSS to display the same text in a tooltip than what is hovered

Tags: css, xhtml, tooltip

I need to know if I can do this with CSS :

I need to display a data on a single line in a report page, but if the data is too long, I do an ellipsis and hide the rest. i.e. I need to display "72348942372394872349834273428973248923" but it is too long. So I display "7234894237239487234...". This, was easily done with CSS. What I need to do now is display the full data when I hover "7234894237239487234..." in a tooltip.

I currently use the `title` attribute to do so, but I want to know if there's a way to only use CSS to have a similar result.

I am using primefaces 5.3

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="ui-noborder my-view">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="label for data : " />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText styleClass="shrinkable"
                          title="72348942372394872349834273428973248923"
                          value="72348942372394872349834273428973248923" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="label for other data : " />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="other data" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

with my current CSS class

```
.shrinkable {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

It works... But I hope there's a more simple way to implement it (like just using the `.shrinkable` class on the tag and the tooltip will display the content of the tag)

---

EDIT :
The resulting HTML would look like this :

```css
.shrinkable {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

//just aweful hard coded patch to
//simulate the effect with primefaces
table {
  max-width: 600px;
}

td {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f2f4" 
class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget ui-noborder my-view" 
role="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f2d6" 
    class="ui-widget-content ui-panelgrid-even" 
    role="row">
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f340" 
      role="gridcell" 
      class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f322">
          label for data : 
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f315" 
      role="gridcell" 
      class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f37f" 
        title="72348942372394872349834273428973248923" 
        class="shrinkable">
          72348942372394872349834273428973248923
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f36e" 
      role="gridcell" 
      class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f358">
          label for other data : 
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f34b" 
      role="gridcell" 
      class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f3ad">
          other data
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here's the resulting page and effect when the cursor hovers over the value on my page :
        [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution : I made a JavaScript function to set the value to all tags that use the CSS class : works just like a charm. I now only need to import this file on the pages where I want it to be used and it works (note that the current code was made only to support h:outputText. I MAY work for some other tags, but you would probably need to modify the code to make it work depending of your needs).

The following code is in the JSF page

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="ui-noborder my-view">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="label for data : " />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText styleClass="shrinkable"  value="72348942372394872349834273428973248923" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="label for other data : " />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="other data" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

And becomes this on the generated page (snippet includes CSS and JavaScript)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 updateShrinking();
});

function updateShrinking() {
    var elements = $(".shrinkable");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var value = elements[i].innerText;
        elements[i].setAttribute("title", value);
    }
}
```

```css
.shrinkable {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

//just aweful hard coded patch to
//simulate the effect with primefaces
table {
  max-width: 600px;
}

td {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f2f4" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget ui-noborder my-view" role="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f2d6" class="ui-widget-content ui-panelgrid-even" role="row">
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f340" role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f322">
          label for data : 
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f315" role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f37f" class="shrinkable">
          72348942372394872349834273428973248923
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f36e" role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f358">
          label for other data : 
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f34b" role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <span id="viewns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_:form:ns_Z7_31H029C0MGHE00APLGNDSL20K4_j_id1385333793_6961f3ad">
            other data
          </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the updateShrinking() function allows me to manually update the shrinking of the page in case I use Ajax calls with PrimeFaces

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.component-class::after {
  content: attr(value);
  display: none;
  // style your component;
}
```

than add

```
.component-class:hover::after {
  display: block; // inline-block etc.
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work : maybe because `<h:outputText>` is transformed in a span with the value within the span tags instead of being kept this form

Comment: can you show me the rendered html ? maybe i can help.

Comment: here you go, just unfold the snippet in the question